# Shifted image when inflate ImageButtons

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I have an activity in my application in which I have to inflate ImageButtons. I thought it was working well at first but noticed that the whole view was shifted down. Am I doing it the wrong way ?

I tried to change some features of the XML template but it didn't solve the problem or work.

```
// Retrieving view's item
    LinearLayout linear = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_existing_picto);

// Retrieving fields from R.drawable
    Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();

// Sorting drawables by name and inserting into the scrollView
    for (final Field field : fields) {
        try {
            if (field.getName().startsWith("dra_")) {
        int currentResId = field.getInt(R.drawable.class);
        ImageButton imageButtonDrawable = (ImageButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_drawable, null);
        imageButtonDrawable.setImageResource(currentResId);
        imageButtonDrawable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("result", field.getName());
            setResult(AddExistingPictoActivity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
            }
        });
        linear.addView(imageButtonDrawable);
        }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem came from the the "layout_gravity" XML attribute of the LinearLayout "linear". Just deleting it fixed the issue.